# R aggregate list of vectors to unique combinations of n vector elements and sum equal combinations

Tags: r, list, vector, aggregate

I am looking for a solution for lists that does similar to what the aggregate() function does with data frames (maybe there is a solution within the aggregate function as well.

I've got a list of numeric vectors with different length:

`mylist <- list(c(1,2,3), c(1,2), c(3,5,6), c(1,2,3,4), c(1,3), c(1,2,3))`

As a result I would like to have a list with unique combinations between elements in the vectors (only the ones that are observed, not all potential ones) like this:

```
unique_combinations <- list(c(1,2), c(1,3), c(1,4), c(2,3), c(2,4), c(3,4), c(3,5), c(3,6), c(5,6), c(1,2,3), c(1,2,4), c(2,3,4), c(3,5,6), c(1,2,3,4))
```

and a vector with the number of times each combination appears in the original list:

```
sum <- c(4, 4, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can use:

```
x <- unlist(lapply(mylist, function(x)
 unlist(lapply(2:length(x), combn, x=x, list), FALSE)), FALSE)
y <- unique(x)
head(y)
#[[1]]
#[1] 1 2
#
#[[2]]
#[1] 1 3
#
#[[3]]
#[1] 2 3
#
#[[4]]
#[1] 1 2 3
#
#[[5]]
#[1] 3 5
#
#[[6]]
#[1] 3 6

table(match(x, y))
# 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 
# 4  4  3  3  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
```

Comment: Thank you. It works. However, it is not feasible with my large data set.